# PHP валидация строки на соответствие формату

Tags: php

как провалидировать строку на соответствие следующему формату? Честно говоря даже не имею представления как происходит валидация на соответствие таким форматам.

```
Иванов Иван Иванович, г. Москва
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace и правила А-Я А-Я А-Я, а-я. А-Я

```
preg_replace('/[^\w_]+/u', '', $data);
```

\w - любое слово
u - для работы юникода

По шаблону выше составляйте правило